# Difference between Object.methodName() and Object..methodName() dart

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, video-player

I was looking at [this](https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/image-video-picker-flutter-1222f3764da9) article about image_picker and video_player library and I saw the code below:

```
_videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_video)..initialize().then((_) {
   setState(() { });
   _videoPlayerController.play();
 });
```

Why are they using ..initialize() instead of .initialize() ?
I tried to use the same code in my project but IDE doesn't let me to use await keyword if I use ..initialize()

> 'await' applied to 'VideoPlayerController', which is not a 'Future'.dart(await_only_futures)

but there is no problem for using the await keyword with .initialize()

So what is the difference between using ..initialize() and .initialize() in this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called cascade notation and is documented in the Dart language tour:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-

The reason why it is used in your example is because the author of that example wants the variable `_videoPlayerController` to be a reference to the object created by `VideoPlayerController.file(_video)` and not the `Future` returned from `then()`.

You could also write the same code in this way:

```
_videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_video);

_videoPlayerController.initialize().then((_) {
   setState(() { });
   _videoPlayerController.play();
 });
```

So the reason why you cannot wait on `VideoPlayerController.file(_video)..initialize().then(` is that the result of that line is not a `Future` but an `VideoPlayerController` object.

Comment: if you use await VideoPlayerController.file(_video).initialize(); would you get the same result? Because await doesn't return a Future and it returns the object reference.

Comment: No, because the return value of `initialize()` is `Future<null>` so if you are using the result from `await` you will get `null`: https://pub.dev/documentation/video_player/latest/video_player/VideoPlayerController/initialize.html

Comment: I was getting the null error but I didn't know why. Thanks a lot for your help :)